# Cannot access a table shown in a Tableau Public Dashboard

Tags: python, web-scraping, tableau-api

I am having issues accessing a table of data from a Tableau Dashboard (website is the following: [click here](https://www.buscadordeempleo.gov.co/)).  I have been searching in Google some ways, and that helped arriving at this point. What I have tried is the following code (based on another thread from here):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

urlPath = "BolsaUnicaemp3/Dashboard12"
r = requests.get(
    f"https://public.tableau.com/views/{urlPath}",
    params= {:showVizHome":"no",    })
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

tableauData = json.loads(soup.find("textarea",{"id": "tsConfigContainer"}).text)
dataUrl = f'https://public.tableau.com{tableauData["vizql_root"]}/bootstrapSession/sessions/{tableauData["sessionid"]}'
r = requests.post(dataUrl, data= {"sheet_id": tableauData["sheetId"],})
dataReg = re.search('\d+;({.*})\d+;({.*})', r.text, re.MULTILINE)
info = json.loads(dataReg.group(1))
data = json.loads(dataReg.group(2))
```

When I see the last `r` request with `info`, I cannot find the table that I want ([Click here to see a screenshot of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ivCB.png)). All that I find is the text above, but nothing related to the results (which are called in Spanish: Resultados). The `data` variable is just empty, so I am lost there.

With this thread, I AM NOT advocating for a complete solution to my problem from you, just a suggestion of an approach/function/package/thread/tutorial that could help me extracting that information. So, do you have any suggestion in this case?

Thank you very much

Again, if you feel that I am saying: "Do my work". that's not my intention. I am just stucked with a very specific question, which is: how to access a table from a Tableau Public Dashboard?

Comment: I can't tell what dashboard you are trying to access: the URL just goes to a general government site. But, if it published in Tableau Public, the publisher can make the direct download of data or the worksheet available or not. getting the data via web-scraping seems a very roundabout route to this if they have made data public.

Comment: I am really sorry. I put the wrong URL. It is the following: https://www.buscadordeempleo.gov.co/ In this website there is a collection of job vacancies for Colombia, but doesn't seem to have available an option to download all the data and that's what I am needing.